# Carthage build failed: Folder already exists and is not an empty directory. failed with exit code 128: fatal: destination path

Tags: git, dependencies, macos-mojave, carthage

I am working on a Swift project and I use Carthage as the dependency management tool.

There were no issues and was able to build the project on Mac OS ***High Sierra*** successfully. But after upgrading to Mac OS ***Mojave***, my project is falling to build.

In this case the framework (AAA) dependency is reached by multiple paths. So Carthage/git tries to clone framework (AAA) multiple times and I think this's causing the issue.

```
Project
|  \
S   P
|   |  \
|   U   |
|   |   |
 \  |  /
   AAA
```

This is the project environment:

- OS: Mac OS Mojave
- Swift: 4.2
- Git: version 2.21.0 (Apple) / version
  2.22.0
- Carthage: 0.33.0

Carthage command:

```
carthage update --use-submodules --platform iOS
```

Error:

> A shell task (/usr/bin/env git clone --bare --quiet https ://bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx_module.git /Users/xx/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/xxx_module) failed with exit code 128: fatal: destination path '/Users/xx/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/xxx_module' already exists and is not an empty directory.

I tried deleting and cleaning project location, git cache also and still not working. Actually deleting folders manually is not working, since Carthage command itself tries to clone the same repo multiple times.

*Note: There were some questions with similar title, but the scope is different on this issue. So I though to post this as a new question.*

Answer (score 0):

Finally this works for me.

```
carthage bootstrap --use-submodules --no-build
```

This is the difference between carthage **update** vs **bootstrap** and it works for me. Still looking for a better explanation. Because previous command (`carthage update --use-submodules --platform iOS`) worked for me until I update the MBP to Mac OS **Mojave**